# Enumerate file names for use in pickString input launch.json

Tags: json, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have a launch.json file for my python project debug configuration. I am using the inputs option and going with pickString to allow the job that I want to debug to be selected from a dropdown. Here is an example:

```
"inputs": [
    {
        "id": "jobName",
        "description": "Enter the job to run: ",
        "type": "pickString",
        "options": ["test", "test1"]
    }
```

This works fine but the issue is that many jobs will be added to the jobs folder and to allow debugging of that specific job I will have to add it manually to launch.json. I am hoping to find a way to instead just read the job names from the jobs folder then use those as the options in my launch.json.

Answer (score 1):

In the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#pick-file) there is a command `extension.commandvariable.file.pickFile` that you can use for this.